# Custom React SVG component not rendering on iOS, renders fine on Desktop

Tags: ios, reactjs, svg

I just made this component to avoid having to load SVG images in React.js, I want to draw my own SVG buttons in this case. Unfortunately, the component I wrote works just fine on Mac or PC Desktop (it renders a blue rectangle) but it does not on iPhone or iPad (tried Safari and Chrome, no luck on iOS). Can you help? This is the component I'm testing:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Svg = (props) => {

    return(

        <svg
            viewBox = {`0 0 ${props.width} ${props.height}`}
        >

            <defs>

                <path
                    id = 'path-main'
                    d = {`
                    M 0, 0
                    L ${props.width}, 0
                    L ${props.width}, ${props.height}
                    L 0, ${props.height}
                    L 0, 0 z
                    `}
                />

            </defs>

            <g>

                <use
                    stroke = 'blue'
                    strokeWidth = '2'
                    fill = 'blue'
                    xlinkHref = '#path-main'
                />

            </g>

        </svg>

    )
}

export default Svg
```

This should be very simple as I haven't done anything special with it yet, I'm just making sure it works across devices and responsively, but alas, it does not. Do you know what I'm missing here? Does iOS not support SVGs drawn in runtime or something?

By the way, the component is just being called this way (obvious but still):

```js
<Svg
  width = '300px'
  height = '50px'
/>
```

Thanks

Edit1: for the record, it also does not render on Mac Desktop Safari, just noticed.

Comment: On iOS every browser is webkit underneath i.e. they are all really identical to Safari when it comes to rendering content.

Comment: Are you implying that one cannot render runtime SVGs on webkit? I know for sure webkit does display SVGs loaded/imported before runtime.

Comment: No, I'm responding to the part of the question where you said you tried Safari and Chrome on iOS by telling you that was bound to give the same result.

Comment: Appreciate it :D did not actually know that :D I solved the issue with the SVG by the way, you can see my own answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the code I wrote above inside my svg tag is not robust enough to work on all browsers. I produced a new simple SVG in Sketch just to test it and this one does appear correctly in all browsers. This would be my test component working in all browsers now:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Svg = (props) => {

    return(

        <svg
            width = {props.width}
            height = {props.height}
            viewBox = {`0 0 ${props.width} ${props.height}`}
        >

            <g
                fill = '#B91799'
                fillRule = 'evenodd'
            >

                <path
                    d = {`
                    M 0, 0
                    L ${props.width}, 0
                    L ${props.width}, ${props.height}
                    L 0, ${props.height}
                    L 0, 0 z
                    `}
                />

            </g>
            
        </svg>

    )
}

export default Svg
```

Edit: As mentioned below by Robert, please note that the problem with the first attempt was the lack of the attributes width and height on the svg element.

Comment: So was the problem the <use> element or the lack of width/height attributes on the <svg> element? Note that it would seem simpler by far to use a fixed size viewBox and then fix all the path values too.

Comment: You are correct, the problem was the lack of the width and height attributes on the <svg> element, I'm gonna add an edit to my answer. I might say that I prefer to have viewBox and svg based on props.width and props.height, for the simple reason that if I want a rectangular button and  my standard size for the viewbox is a square I'm going to end up with unnecessary blank space being written to the DOM, even if it does not showw. I think keeping both dependent on the props being sent is cleaner :D Thanks!